# How do I get data from a web form?

Tags: java, submit, forms

As a pet project I want to build a program that translate from English to Hebrew.
The way I want to make the translation itself is using a web site called [morfix](http://milon.morfix.co.il/).
In this site can enter an English word and after pressing the "תרגום" (translate) button 
the translation is brought.

My first choice is to write this program in Java, and I tried using [htmlunit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/), but it does not work beacuse i guess the site uses AJAX to bring the results.

In what languge can I implement the part that submit the web form?
How can I integrate Java with that other language?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also send your request without form submit: `http://milon.morfix.co.il/?q=try`

Comment: How did yo uncover did possibility?

Answer (score 2):

You need a http analyzer to check what's going on when that button is pressed (Try Live HTTp headers for firefox). Then you can use any language to make the web request.

Comment: After checking the site, basically it submit the form with the word to be translated in a hidden field named "q1".